# Structuring Coq code

Tags: function, types, structure, coq

I have the usual setup: first I define some types, then some functions from those types. However, since there are many ways to formalize the thing I do, I will do it in 3 versions. For simplicity (and to maintain an overview), I want my code in one file. **I also want to minimize repetitive code**. To this end, a setup w/ 3 `Module`s for specific stuff and general definitions in front of them might work -- but not in the type of situation described below:

1. A general `Definition` of function `f: A -> B`, accessible in all
   sections (or modules)
2. Module- (or section-) specific definitions of `A`
3. `f` must be computable in all sections (or modules)

What setup do you recommend me to use?

Comment: Have you looked at [A Tutorial on Using Modules](https://coq.inria.fr/cocorico/ModuleSystemTutorial)?

Comment: Thanks, took a look at it now. It seems that `Module Type` can contain only `Axiom`s and `Parameter`s. Since `f` would have a body (I've defined it w/ `Definition`), I couldn't put it into `Module Type`. ATM I don't know how to satisfy points 1-2 in my question (haven't even seriously considered 3 yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Require Import Arith.

(* Create a module type for some type A with some general properties. *)
Module Type ModA.
  Parameter A: Type.
  Axiom a_dec: forall a b:A, {a=b}+{a<>b}.
End ModA.

(* Define the function that uses the A type in another module 
   that imports a ModA type module *)

Module FMod (AM: (ModA)).
  Import AM.
  Definition f (a1 a2:A) := if a_dec a1 a2 then 1 else 2.
End FMod.

(* Here's how to use f in another module *)
Module FTheory (AM:ModA).
  Module M := FMod AM.
  Import M.
  Import AM.

  Theorem f_theorem: forall a, f a a = 1.
    intros. compute. destruct (a_dec _ _).
    auto. congruence.
  Qed.
End FTheory.  

(* Eventually, instatiate the type A in some way,
   using subtyping '<:'. *)

Module ModANat <: ModA.
  Definition A := nat.
  Theorem a_dec: forall a b:A, {a=b}+{a<>b}.
    apply eq_nat_dec.
  Qed.
 End ModANat. 

(* Here we use f for your particular type A *)
Module FModNat := FMod ModANat.

Compute (FModNat.f 3 4).

Recursive Extraction FModNat.f.

Goal FModNat.f 3 3 = 1.
  Module M := FTheory ModANat.
  apply M.f_theorem.
Qed.
```

Comment: PS. You can (more conveniently) start computing `f` on `nat` already in `FTheory` -- just insert `Variable na:> nat -> A. Compute f 3 4.` after `Import AM.` there

Comment: The idea here was to show how to separate out general properties, such as being a group, being decidable, being ordered etc, and create general theories about them. Later those theories can be specialized to particular instances such as matrices, lists, trees, etc.  While putting lemmas that refer to a particular instance (such as nat, which are decidable) into the general theory of decidable types is possible, but breaks the separation between things that are true for all decidable types and things that are true specifically for nats.